# Syntax error in sql Query Design

Tags: sql

I have design one query such as

```
Select Temp3.*

From (
              (Select temp1.alletec_ce1name,temp1.employeeid, count (temp1.alletec_mifid) AS MifAssign,alletec_mifid
     from (select  MIF.alletec_ce1name,User1.employeeid,MIF.alletec_mifid from Filteredalletec_mif as MIF FULL OUTER JOIN FilteredSystemUser As User1 on MIF.alletec_ce1=User1.systemuserid 
              FULL OUTER JOIN FilteredBusinessUnit as BU ON User1.businessunitid=BU.businessunitid 
              where MIF.alletec_organisationname='Konica Minolta India' AND MIF.alletec_cityname ='Delhi' AND
                     MIF.alletec_regionname ='North' ) as temp1
Group by temp1.alletec_mifid,temp1.alletec_ce1name,temp1.employeeid ) as Temp2 Inner Join FilteredIncident As Incident On Incident.alletec_serialnomif=Temp2.alletec_mifid ) as temp3
```

Now the issue is it is showing the Syntax error near the first from. What can be the possible reason for that. Thanks in advance.

I have one more query, such as

```
with temp2 (
alletec_ce1name,
employeeid,
alletec_mifid,
alletec_cityname,
alletec_regionname

)
as(
Select temp1.alletec_ce1name,temp1.employeeid, temp1.alletec_mifid, temp1.alletec_cityname,temp1.alletec_regionname
from (select  MIF.alletec_ce1name,User1.employeeid,MIF.alletec_mifid,  MIF.alletec_regionname, MIF.alletec_cityname from Filteredalletec_mif as MIF FULL OUTER JOIN FilteredSystemUser As User1 on MIF.alletec_ce1=User1.systemuserid 
              FULL OUTER JOIN FilteredBusinessUnit as BU ON User1.businessunitid=BU.businessunitid 
             where MIF.alletec_organisationname='Konica Minolta India' AND (MIF.alletec_cityname ='Delhi') AND
                     (MIF.alletec_regionname ='North') ) as temp1
                     )


select temp2.alletec_ce1name,temp2.employeeid, temp2.alletec_regionname,temp2.alletec_cityname, count(alletec_mifid) as MIFASSIGN,
   Incident.alletec_casecalltypename
from temp2  Left Outer join FilteredIncident As Incident On Incident.alletec_serialnomif=temp2.alletec_mifid 
group by  temp2.alletec_ce1name,temp2.employeeid,temp2.alletec_mifid,temp2.alletec_regionname,temp2.alletec_cityname,
   Incident.alletec_casecalltypename
```

now as with i got one temporary table. i wish to have one more temporary table so that can incorporate my last executable table values from `temp2`. do have a look if u can help for either. Thanks

Comment: A `.` would indicate you are also providing a column name, which is missing. Furthermore... I don't see `Temp3` anywhere else in your query unless you didn't post everything.

Comment: Now check. Actually as the syntax showing an error. So no Column is accessible though it.

Comment: you still have `temp3.` there should be a column or a star after the `.`

Comment: Now check. i have placed one more query and just wish to have one more level of nesting.

Answer (score 0):

Your query amounts to

```
select
    *
from
    (table) as temp3
```

This isn't valid, you can't put the parentheses there. The extra level of nesting is broken. You either need to do something like:

```
select
    *
from
    table
```

or something like

```
select
    *
from (
    select
        *
    from
        table
    ) as temp3
```

Your first query can probably be simplified to:

```
Select 
    *
From (
    select  
        MIF.alletec_ce1name,
        User1.employeeid,
        MIF.alletec_mifid,
        count (MIF.alltec_mifid) as MifAssign
    from 
        Filteredalletec_mif as MIF 
            full outer join
        FilteredSystemUser As User1 
            on MIF.alletec_ce1 = User1.systemuserid 
            full outer join 
        FilteredBusinessUnit as BU 
            on User1.businessunitid=BU.businessunitid 
    where 
        MIF.alletec_organisationname = 'Konica Minolta India' AND 
        MIF.alletec_cityname ='Delhi' AND
        MIF.alletec_regionname ='North' 
    group by
        MIF.alletec_mifid,
        MIF.alletec_ce1name,
        User1.employeeid
    ) as temp1
        Inner Join 
    FilteredIncident As Incident 
        On Incident.alletec_serialnomif = Temp1.alletec_mifid;
```

Comment: Thanks and what about the second query. if i wish to have a complete table as a another temp3. so that i can use that temp3 table for further calculation

Comment: Okay. then my first query wont serve my purpose and what can be done in second query?

Comment: If i try to put this query into one more nested level. how will i do that?

Comment: Just as an asside: Oracle is fine with `select * from (table) temp3`  but doesn't like AS in inline views. I'm guessing you're assuming SQL server

Comment: `select * from (query) as temp99`

Answer (score 0):

Count up your parentheses, I think they are mismatched.